# Individual Points Not Showing Up on Plotly (but do show up in ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, scatter-plot, plotly

So I'm having trouble with scatter charts in ggplot vs PLotly. In my actual code I'm using a K-means cluster to decide which color to make each of my data points. However, some of my clusters only have one data point and those clusters aren't showing up on plotly (but do show up on ggplot2). Here's a simplified example of what I'm experiencing:

```
shinyUI(    
   mainPanel(
     plotlyOutput('plot2'),
     plotOutput('plot4'))
     )
```

Just a basic shinyUI page. Here's what I have on the server.R side:

```
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({

    qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=ifelse(wt==2.620, 'red', 'blue'),          
    size=ifelse(wt==2.620, 8, 4))

  }) 

  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({

    gg4 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=ifelse(wt==2.620, 'red', 'blue'), 
    size=ifelse(wt==2.620, 8, 4))
    p4 <- ggplotly(gg4)

  })
```

So that produces the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd3Tj.png). The top graph in that case is the Plotly image, while the bottom is the ggplot2 one. As you can see the blue dot only shows up in the ggplot2 one but can't be found in the Plotly. I chose to single out "wt==2.620" since there's only data point in mtcars with that value.

However, once I switch to the following code:

```
  output$plot4 <- renderPlot({
    print(mtcars[,2])
    print(mtcars[,3])
    qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=ifelse(mpg==10.4, 'red', 'blue'))

  }) 

  output$plot2 <- renderPlotly({

    gg4 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars, colour=ifelse(mpg==10.4, 'red', 'blue'))
    p4 <- ggplotly(gg4)

  })
```

I used mpg==10.4 here since there are two cars within mtcars with mpg==10.4. This produces the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLvoz.png). You can see that it has the blue point both on the plotly plot and the ggplot scatter. I haven't been able to find a solution to this, so any sort of advice would be really appreciated!

Comment: If ggplot2 is working is there a specific reason why you want to use plotly.

Comment: I'd report it to plotly. The issue is present even if the data is partitioned outside of the ggplot() call. Strangely enough, if the same data (with the additional variable) is imported into plot.ly's web interface and then plotted, it works as intended. I'm new to plotly and don't know if you can see the underlying call, or whether it would be useful at all.